# Why is it so fast to create an index on a table?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index, optimization

While optimizing my query in Postgres, I noted that creating an index is always very fast, less than 1 second on a table with millions of rows.

But if there's no index, a query would take a few minutes or even more!

In my mind, when creating an index, Postgres has to scan all data of the columns those need to be indexed on at least once. So this operation should be similar to a query with a filter on the same columns that needs a sequence scan on a table.

Why is creating an index dramatically faster than a sequence scanning query?

Comment: I can assure you, index creation is not always fast.  You will not to provide a reproducible example for any hope at a meaningful answer.

Comment: I am puzzled by the speed of creating an index, compared to queries based on a seq scan at times, too. The index has to be registered in system tables and persisted, no less.

Comment: Perhaps it does the timeconsuming work in the background?  Could you actually use the new index immediately after you "created" it?  Or did a query still do a table scan?

Answer (score -1):

Usually create a index on one column is much faster than you thought it should be.

For example when you create an index on User.name, usually the column will not exceed 31bytes and row will not exceed 100bytes(20bytes for username, 31bytes for email, 4bytes for id, 40 bytes for password) and if there were 1 million records in your table, the size to read will be `100 * 1000000 / 1024 / 1024 = 95 MiB`.

Which is quite small compared to the io speed (usually 100MiB/s).

Comment: Postgres reads and writes pages, not individual bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I change the column to row.

Comment: Thanks, but the page can contain more than one row...